# Using Playscape SDK for Unity, can I check availability of Adcolony Ads?

Tags: android, playscape

I am implementing Playscape's SDK for android 1.13 and during development we are running into the issue where if the user has watched too many ads, no more ads will be served from Adcolony, providing this message in the logcat debug output:
"Ad is not ready to be played, as Adcolony currently has no videos available to be played in zone [zone id]." another situation where ads fail to play is related to hitting the "daily cap" of ads, which according to the Adcolony site, seems to be related to a setting in the SDK.

Can we somehow query the SDK to understand before the event happens, if there are no more AdColony ads available?

Best Regards
Jakob

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this capability doesnt exist as part of the SDK. As of now the parameter value is set by Playscape. Please contact our Data scientist Nadav to consult.